# Unwanted code in my site causing display problems

Tags: html, wordpress, google-chrome, header, themes

I have a WordPress site, running the latest Divi theme. it's currently in maintenance mode as I recently noticed a random space between the header and top of page, which only shows on Chrome and IE, but not in the Firefox. Through dev tools I found this bit of code in the body, which, seems, causing it.

I deleted my theme and reinstalled a fresh version, but the problem persists. I've also tried activating a different theme, but this didn't help, either. Dealing with support has been slow and I'm anxious to get the site up and running again.

Is it time for me to do a new clean WP install?

[image]

Header.php code for Divi theme:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<?php
    elegant_description();
    elegant_keywords();
    elegant_canonical();

    /**
     * Fires in the head, before {@see wp_head()} is called. This action can be used to
     * insert elements into the beginning of the head before any styles or scripts.
     *
     * @since 1.0
     */
    do_action( 'et_head_meta' );

    $template_directory_uri = get_template_directory_uri();
?>

    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.documentElement.className = 'js';
    </script>

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php
    $product_tour_enabled = et_builder_is_product_tour_enabled();
    $page_container_style = $product_tour_enabled ? ' style="padding-top: 0px;"' : ''; ?>
    <div id="page-container"<?php echo $page_container_style; ?>>
<?php
    if ( $product_tour_enabled || is_page_template( 'page-template-blank.php' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $et_secondary_nav_items = et_divi_get_top_nav_items();

    $et_phone_number = $et_secondary_nav_items->phone_number;

    $et_email = $et_secondary_nav_items->email;

    $et_contact_info_defined = $et_secondary_nav_items->contact_info_defined;

    $show_header_social_icons = $et_secondary_nav_items->show_header_social_icons;

    $et_secondary_nav = $et_secondary_nav_items->secondary_nav;

    $et_top_info_defined = $et_secondary_nav_items->top_info_defined;

    $et_slide_header = 'slide' === et_get_option( 'header_style', 'left' ) || 'fullscreen' === et_get_option( 'header_style', 'left' ) ? true : false;
?>

    <?php if ( $et_top_info_defined && ! $et_slide_header || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
        <?php ob_start(); ?>
        <div id="top-header"<?php echo $et_top_info_defined ? '' : 'style="display: none;"'; ?>>
            <div class="container clearfix">

            <?php if ( $et_contact_info_defined ) : ?>

                <div id="et-info">
                <?php if ( '' !== ( $et_phone_number = et_get_option( 'phone_number' ) ) ) : ?>
                    <span id="et-info-phone"><?php echo et_sanitize_html_input_text( $et_phone_number ); ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ( '' !== ( $et_email = et_get_option( 'header_email' ) ) ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( 'mailto:' . $et_email ); ?>"><span id="et-info-email"><?php echo esc_html( $et_email ); ?></span></a>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php
                if ( true === $show_header_social_icons ) {
                    get_template_part( 'includes/social_icons', 'header' );
                } ?>
                </div> <!-- #et-info -->

            <?php endif; // true === $et_contact_info_defined ?>

                <div id="et-secondary-menu">
                <?php
                    if ( ! $et_contact_info_defined && true === $show_header_social_icons ) {
                        get_template_part( 'includes/social_icons', 'header' );
                    } else if ( $et_contact_info_defined && true === $show_header_social_icons ) {
                        ob_start();

                        get_template_part( 'includes/social_icons', 'header' );

                        $duplicate_social_icons = ob_get_contents();

                        ob_end_clean();

                        printf(
                            '<div class="et_duplicate_social_icons">
                                %1$s
                            </div>',
                            $duplicate_social_icons
                        );
                    }

                    if ( '' !== $et_secondary_nav ) {
                        echo $et_secondary_nav;
                    }

                    et_show_cart_total();
                ?>
                </div> <!-- #et-secondary-menu -->

            </div> <!-- .container -->
        </div> <!-- #top-header -->
    <?php
        $top_header = ob_get_clean();

        /**
         * Filters the HTML output for the top header.
         *
         * @since ??
         *
         * @param string $top_header
         */
        echo apply_filters( 'et_html_top_header', $top_header );
    ?>
    <?php endif; // true ==== $et_top_info_defined ?>

    <?php if ( $et_slide_header || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
        <?php ob_start(); ?>
        <div class="et_slide_in_menu_container">
            <?php if ( 'fullscreen' === et_get_option( 'header_style', 'left' ) || is_customize_preview() ) { ?>
                <span class="mobile_menu_bar et_toggle_fullscreen_menu"></span>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php
                if ( $et_contact_info_defined || true === $show_header_social_icons || false !== et_get_option( 'show_search_icon', true ) || class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) || is_customize_preview() ) { ?>
                    <div class="et_slide_menu_top">

                    <?php if ( 'fullscreen' === et_get_option( 'header_style', 'left' ) ) { ?>
                        <div class="et_pb_top_menu_inner">
                    <?php } ?>
            <?php }

                if ( true === $show_header_social_icons ) {
                    get_template_part( 'includes/social_icons', 'header' );
                }

                et_show_cart_total();
            ?>
            <?php if ( false !== et_get_option( 'show_search_icon', true ) || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
                <?php if ( 'fullscreen' !== et_get_option( 'header_style', 'left' ) ) { ?>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php } ?>
                <form role="search" method="get" class="et-search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        printf( '<input type="search" class="et-search-field" placeholder="%1$s" value="%2$s" name="s" title="%3$s" />',
                            esc_attr__( 'Search &hellip;', 'Divi' ),
                            get_search_query(),
                            esc_attr__( 'Search for:', 'Divi' )
                        );
                    ?>
                    <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit_header"></button>
                </form>
            <?php endif; // true === et_get_option( 'show_search_icon', false ) ?>

            <?php if ( $et_contact_info_defined ) : ?>

                <div id="et-info">
                <?php if ( '' !== ( $et_phone_number = et_get_option( 'phone_number' ) ) ) : ?>
                    <span id="et-info-phone"><?php echo et_sanitize_html_input_text( $et_phone_number ); ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ( '' !== ( $et_email = et_get_option( 'header_email' ) ) ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( 'mailto:' . $et_email ); ?>"><span id="et-info-email"><?php echo esc_html( $et_email ); ?></span></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </div> <!-- #et-info -->

            <?php endif; // true === $et_contact_info_defined ?>
            <?php if ( $et_contact_info_defined || true === $show_header_social_icons || false !== et_get_option( 'show_search_icon', true ) || class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) || is_customize_preview() ) { ?>
                <?php if ( 'fullscreen' === et_get_option( 'header_style', 'left' ) ) { ?>
                    </div> <!-- .et_pb_top_menu_inner -->
                <?php } ?>

                </div> <!-- .et_slide_menu_top -->
            <?php } ?>

            <div class="et_pb_fullscreen_nav_container">
                <?php
                    $slide_nav = '';
                    $slide_menu_class = 'et_mobile_menu';

                    $slide_nav = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'container' => '', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'echo' => false, 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) );
                    $slide_nav .= wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary-menu', 'container' => '', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'echo' => false, 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) );
                ?>

                <ul id="mobile_menu_slide" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $slide_menu_class ); ?>">

                <?php
                    if ( '' == $slide_nav ) :
                ?>
                        <?php if ( 'on' == et_get_option( 'divi_home_link' ) ) { ?>
                            <li <?php if ( is_home() ) echo( 'class="current_page_item"' ); ?>><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Home', 'Divi' ); ?></a></li>
                        <?php }; ?>

                        <?php show_page_menu( $slide_menu_class, false, false ); ?>
                        <?php show_categories_menu( $slide_menu_class, false ); ?>
                <?php
                    else :
                        echo( $slide_nav );
                    endif;
                ?>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
        $slide_header = ob_get_clean();

        /**
         * Filters the HTML output for the slide header.
         *
         * @since ??
         *
         * @param string $top_header
         */
        echo apply_filters( 'et_html_slide_header', $slide_header );
    ?>
    <?php endif; // true ==== $et_slide_header ?>

    <?php ob_start(); ?>
        <header id="main-header" data-height-onload="<?php echo esc_attr( et_get_option( 'menu_height', '66' ) ); ?>">
            <div class="container clearfix et_menu_container">
            <?php
                $logo = ( $user_logo = et_get_option( 'divi_logo' ) ) && '' != $user_logo
                    ? $user_logo
                    : $template_directory_uri . '/images/logo.png';

                ob_start();
            ?>
                <div class="logo_container">
                    <span class="logo_helper"></span>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo esc_attr( $logo ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" id="logo" data-height-percentage="<?php echo esc_attr( et_get_option( 'logo_height', '54' ) ); ?>" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php
                $logo_container = ob_get_clean();

                /**
                 * Filters the HTML output for the logo container.
                 *
                 * @since ??
                 *
                 * @param string $logo_container
                 */
                echo apply_filters( 'et_html_logo_container', $logo_container );
            ?>
                <div id="et-top-navigation" data-height="<?php echo esc_attr( et_get_option( 'menu_height', '66' ) ); ?>" data-fixed-height="<?php echo esc_attr( et_get_option( 'minimized_menu_height', '40' ) ); ?>">
                    <?php if ( ! $et_slide_header || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
                        <nav id="top-menu-nav">
                        <?php
                            $menuClass = 'nav';
                            if ( 'on' == et_get_option( 'divi_disable_toptier' ) ) $menuClass .= ' et_disable_top_tier';
                            $primaryNav = '';

                            $primaryNav = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'container' => '', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'menu_class' => $menuClass, 'menu_id' => 'top-menu', 'echo' => false ) );

                            if ( '' == $primaryNav ) :
                        ?>
                            <ul id="top-menu" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $menuClass ); ?>">
                                <?php if ( 'on' == et_get_option( 'divi_home_link' ) ) { ?>
                                    <li <?php if ( is_home() ) echo( 'class="current_page_item"' ); ?>><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Home', 'Divi' ); ?></a></li>
                                <?php }; ?>

                                <?php show_page_menu( $menuClass, false, false ); ?>
                                <?php show_categories_menu( $menuClass, false ); ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php
                            else :
                                echo( $primaryNav );
                            endif;
                        ?>
                        </nav>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php
                    if ( ! $et_top_info_defined && ( ! $et_slide_header || is_customize_preview() ) ) {
                        et_show_cart_total( array(
                            'no_text' => true,
                        ) );
                    }
                    ?>

                    <?php if ( $et_slide_header || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
                        <span class="mobile_menu_bar et_pb_header_toggle et_toggle_<?php echo esc_attr( et_get_option( 'header_style', 'left' ) ); ?>_menu"></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if ( ( false !== et_get_option( 'show_search_icon', true ) && ! $et_slide_header ) || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
                    <div id="et_top_search">
                        <span id="et_search_icon"></span>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; // true === et_get_option( 'show_search_icon', false ) ?>

                    <?php

                    /**
                     * Fires at the end of the 'et-top-navigation' element, just before its closing tag.
                     *
                     * @since 1.0
                     */
                    do_action( 'et_header_top' );

                    ?>
                </div> <!-- #et-top-navigation -->
            </div> <!-- .container -->
            <div class="et_search_outer">
                <div class="container et_search_form_container">
                    <form role="search" method="get" class="et-search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        printf( '<input type="search" class="et-search-field" placeholder="%1$s" value="%2$s" name="s" title="%3$s" />',
                            esc_attr__( 'Search &hellip;', 'Divi' ),
                            get_search_query(),
                            esc_attr__( 'Search for:', 'Divi' )
                        );
                    ?>
                    </form>
                    <span class="et_close_search_field"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header> <!-- #main-header -->
    <?php
        $main_header = ob_get_clean();

        /**
         * Filters the HTML output for the main header.
         *
         * @since ??
         *
         * @param string $main_header
         */
        echo apply_filters( 'et_html_main_header', $main_header );
    ?>
        <div id="et-main-area">
    <?php
        /**
         * Fires after the header, before the main content is output.
         *
         * @since ??
         */
        do_action( 'et_before_main_content' );
```

Comment: what theme/childe theme your're using? why are your metas out of your `<head>` tag?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan I'm using the Divi theme. I had no child theme before but when this problem started I installed one (didn't help, changing theme altogether didn't either). I don't know why my metas aren't in the head tag :/ btw. All plugins are deactivates. Also deleted the newest ones just in case.

Comment: can you add the code from the file: `wp-content/themes/Divi/header.php` in the your question?

Comment: your `header.php` file looks ok. I think, it may be some perfomance/cache plugin or code, which moved all content from `<head>` tag into body, and it's causes that empty space. which plugins related to perfomance, or maybe some code, you have into your website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my site had malware.

other strange things were going on so I contacted my host. They scanned the site and malware came up. I got it cleaned and now it's fine!